# Formatting excel file using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I am currently trying to take a csv file generated from a VBScript, and use powershell to convert it to an xls then save it. (Using it as an offline Database file)  Problem, is that one column (Column E) is for SKU's and has leading 0's that get lost during the translation. I am getting errors when trying the following.  Powershell is new to me, so I could be making a simple mistake:

```
$xl = new-object -comobject excel.application
$xl.visible = $true
$Workbook = $xl.workbooks.open("file location.csv")
$Worksheets = $Workbooks.worksheets
$Worksheets.Columns.("E").NumberFormat = "00000000000"
$Workbook.SaveAs("file location.xls",1)
$Workbook.Saved = $True
$xl.Quit()
```

EDIT: I got it to work!  Here's the following, if anyone has any pointers:

```
$excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
$excel.visible = $true
$Workbook = $excel.workbooks.open("file location.csv")
$Worksheets = $Workbooks.worksheets
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$Range = $Excel.Range("E:E").EntireColumn
$Range.NumberFormat = "00000000000"
$Workbook.SaveAs("file location.xls",1)
$Workbook.Saved = $True
$excel.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same thing with changing

`$Worksheets.Columns.("E").NumberFormat = "00000000000"F15`

to

`$workbook.ActiveSheet.Columns.Item("E").NumberFormat = "00000000000"`

from the first example to have less code.